# number of surjective function from a set [k] to [n]

Tags: combinatorics, functions, solution-verification, inclusion-exclusion

I'm trying to prove that the number of surjective function from a set [k] to [n] is :

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}(-1)^{i}(n-i)^{k}$$

So I've started to create a set A which contains the number of functions from [k] to [n] and I have $|A|=n^{k}$ and then I have the sets $B_{I}$ which are the sets that contains the functions that missed i elements form [n]. I know now that I have to alternatively subtract and add them all up but I don't know how to make a formal proof that's shows that this is in fact the formula that we were looking for.

Comment: Hint: Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: I know that I have to use that but I don't see how